# What are 6 different ways to stack a rectangular prism?

Tags: geometry

The question I'm currently trying to solve calls for 6 different ways to stack rectangular prisms evenly. So, each outcome must differentiate from one another, in terms of surface area. I was able to come up with 5 different ways, but I'm stuck on the last one.

$L = 19.7 \mathbb{cm}; \ W = 17 \mathbb{cm}; \  H = 12 \mathbb{cm}$

1. $4784\mathbb{cm}^2$
2. $4046.8\mathbb{cm}^2$
3. $4978.4\mathbb{cm}^2$
4. $4193\mathbb{cm}^2$
5. $4440.8\mathbb{cm}^2 $

6) ______?

P.S Does anyone know any online drawing tools so I can draw it for you?
*I'm stacking 4 rectangular prisms.

Comment: How many prisms are you stacking?

Comment: I fail to see how can you get $1958.60$. The smallest area I get get for stacking two cuboids together is already $2431.40$.

Comment: How can you *stalk* four prisms at the same time?;)

Comment: G-Man, I'm stacking 4. 
Achille, Yes, I realize my mistake. I fixed it.
G-Man, Hahahahahaha nice one. I'll fix that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I find 3917.2 by stacking them in a square with the 19.7 by 17 and 19.7 by 12 faces touching.  You have the other two ways of choosing two pairs of faces to touch.